# Connecting to a hidden Wi-Fi network Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, wifi

I install Arch Linux 8.1. I'm trying to connect to the network via Wi-fi via the iwd package according to the manual, the problem is that my network is hidden and is not detected in the list by `station wlan1 get-networks`. Even if you connect directly with the correct SSID and key, the network is still not located. How can I find a hidden network through iwd, or through another tool?

Answer (score 3):

Searching iwd source code it appears there is a command for connecting to a hidden network as found in [this commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/wireless/iwd.git/commit/?id=f545f94581ca7dac839d2852678c4a6833387edb).

Please try using `station <device> connect-hidden <ssid>`
Im not sure this will work but it's worth a shot.
This should ask you for the passphrase if not try `iwctl --passphrase <passphrase> station <device> connect-hidden <ssid>`

Comment: `iwctl help | grep connect-hidden`